# xcode 8.3 Could not build module 'Darwin' error

Tags: ios, xcode

I run into this error at least a few times a week and I have tried all of the solutions I could find on this site, but the only solution that I have that works is to either create a completely new project (a time consuming process) or sometimes even that doesn't work and I need to completely remove Xcode from my computer and reinstall and then create a completely new project (an even longer process).    Does anyone know the root cause of this error? If this did not happen with such frequency the above solutions would be workable.    I do have a static library as part of my project, could that be a problem?   The one way I know to trigger this error is to remove the static library for the simulator and replace it with the static library needed to run on an actual device.

Comment: Can you give some context for where this error appears and what's happening at the time it does?

Comment: It appears at random when building the code, unless I switch the libraries.  That is, I remove the static library that can be used for running the simulator  in build phases and add the static library that is used for running the app on a device.    Here is the full error message from my xcode  "Could not build module 'Darwin' objc.h" and then it is followed by the error messages While building module 'Foundation', While building module 'ObjectiveC'

Comment: One other time this happens consistently is when I have not worked on the project ( it was building and running fine) for a while (a few days or weeks) and I reopen Xcode and try to build, this error will appear.    So the bottom line, is sometimes I have done nothing and this error shows up.   It is the inconsistency of the issue that is so confusing.   I cannot predict when it will happen except the two times I have mentioned, switching static libraries and not working on the code for a while.

Comment: What is it you're trying to build?  Normally (as in 99.many9s% of the time), you just **use** Foundation or ObjectiveC.  It sounds as if the problem isn't that you get an error when building those modules but rather that something thinks it should build them in the first place!

Comment: I am using an open source library that I translated into objective from java using j2objc..    The calls to foundation are part of the .a file that is needed from j2objc.    So the root cause in this case could be because of the library.    Still doesn't explain why it ever works and it might mean there is no solution,

Comment: Calling Foundation is fine; building Foundation doesn't quite make sense to me.

Comment: Thank you, your comment allowed me to think about this from a different way so I found the answer.    It was related to the j2objc include files, they cannot be added in a recursive mode in the header files search path.